# Почему не работает бд access

Tags: access

Пишу курсовую и создаю бд"расчет платы жильцов по жкх", есть несколько таблиц с показаниями счётчиков, которые выводятся в запрос, проблема в том, что выводится только данные из одной таблицы и повторяются на каждом плательщике.Полагаю проблема в связях, но исправить не могу.

Comment: *есть несколько таблиц с показаниями счётчиков* Почему несколько?

Comment: Мы даже по фотографиям не лечим... и уж тем более по описанию фотографии. Где факты-то?

Comment: Могу скинуть вам в телеграмм, тут с этим у меня проблемы